# Dovecot can't receive external mails, AddressValueError

Tags: postfix, dovecot

After updating

**from** dovecot-1:2.2.10-7.el7.x86_64 **to** 1:2.2.10-8.el7.x86_64
**from** dovecot-mysql-1:2.2.10-7.el7.x86_64 **to** 1:2.2.10-8.el7.x86_64
**from** dovecot-pigeonhole-1:2.2.10-7.el7.x86_64 **to** 1:2.2.10-8.el7.x86_64

I can not receive emails from external mail addresses. Sending mails works fine as well as receiving them when they are send from a local mail address.
In /var/log/maillog I have the following Error:

```
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname postfix/smtpd[28227]: connect from sonic304-22.consmr.mail.ir2.yahoo.com[77.238.179.147]
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname postfix/smtpd[28227]: Anonymous TLS connection established from sonic304-22.consmr.mail.ir2.yahoo.com[77.238.179.147]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]:  File "/usr/libexec/postfix/policyd-spf", line 707, in <module>
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]:    instance_dict, configData, peruser)
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]:  File "/usr/libexec/postfix/policyd-spf", line 419, in _spfcheck
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]:    res = spf.check2(ip, helo_fake_sender, helo, querytime=configData.get('Lookup_Time'))
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spf.py", line 297, in check2
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]:    receiver=receiver,timeout=timeout,verbose=verbose,querytime=querytime).check()
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spf.py", line 378, in __init__
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]:    self.set_ip(i)
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spf.py", line 405, in set_ip
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]:    self.ipaddr = ipaddress.ip_address(i)
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaddress.py", line 163, in ip_address
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]:    ' a unicode object?' % address)
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname policyd-spf[28530]: AddressValueError: '77.238.179.147' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address. Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode object?
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname postfix/spawn[28087]: warning: command /usr/libexec/postfix/policyd-spf exit status 1
Oct 30 15:11:21 hostname postfix/smtpd[28227]: warning: premature end-of-input on private/policy-spf while reading input attribute name
```

Any ideas what's the cause of the error?

Comment: Dovecot is not responsible for receiving mail, that would be postfix. And the problem is with policyd-spf. Looks like your python installation is broken. Reinstalling python and the python packages relevant to policyd-spf could fix it.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yum reinstall python pypolicyd-spf did not fix the problem. Python is Version: 2.7.5-58.el7 and pypolicyd-spf is: 1.3.2-2.el7

Comment: Seems like a bug in pypolicyd-spf version 1.3.2-2.el7 https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1506445

Comment: And this one I found for centOs specific https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=12393 which appears to be the exact issue I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem. As stated in the comments, the corresponding Bug report is https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=12393.

The fix provided in the [comment](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=12393#c30486) by Yohei TOMIYAMA works for me.

Before you fix it, make sure it's the same bug. The following versions of the packages must match:

```
yum list installed | grep pypolicyd-spf
pypolicyd-spf.noarch   1.3.2-2.el7   @epel

yum list installed | grep python-ipaddress
python-ipaddress.noarch   1.0.16-2.el7  @base
```

The package python-ipaddress may only be required by pypolicyd-spf or this fix will break anything else. You can check this with

```
rpm -q --whatrequires python-ipaddress
pypolicyd-spf-1.3.2-2.el7.noarch
```

Now the fix:

```
rpm -e --nodeps python-ipaddress
vim /usr/libexec/postfix/policyd-spf
```

At line 40 change the line as following:

```
- import ipaddress
+ import ipaddr as ipaddress
```

That's it. Depending on the configuration of the mail-provider they retry sending the mail in intervals. After an hour or so most of the missing mails should be received.

As mentioned above, thanks to Yohei TOMIYAMA for providing this fix.